# Ckeditor deleting content with lists

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

We are using CKEditor 4.2 in our project and we can not upgrade version for now. We have an issue in the main library file. If a List (LI) contains a paragraph (`<p>`) tag, and we click on Increase Indent, It erase all content Here is the working HTML.

```
<ol start="7"&gt;

<li>
<p>This LI contains P tag</p>
</li>
<li>This lis is without P tag</li>
    <li>Hardcopy Options:
<ul>
    <li>The report is only emailed.</li>
</ul>
<font face="raleway"><font face="raleway"> </font></font></li>
```

If We select First LI and click on Increase indent, It will deleted nested list.

Comment: Same issue with library.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/release/CKEditor-4.2

Comment: CKEditor 4.2 is a very old version. Try to reproduce it on the latest version (use the website demo or sample). If it's still an issue there, file a bug report at https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/new/choose. If it cannot be reproduced anymore then you can only upgrade as CKEditor does not backport fixes.